# How to hide hierarchy grid toolbar custom button in kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, hide, toolbar

[image]Here is my hierarchy grid toolbar.

I put new button in toolbar and that id is CustomButton.

I want to hide that button onclick but when ajax call is success.

I tried $("#CustomButton").remove(); And Also $("#CustomButton").hide(); This code through my button is not hide.

How to hide that button?

```
toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "@T("Admin.Common.AddNewRecord")" },{ name: "add_user", template: '<a class="k-button" id="CustomButton" onclick="oleuminvoiceDocketSubmit()">Send invoice to customer</a>'}],

//Custom Toolbar Button Click
function oleuminvoiceDocketSubmit()
{
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("Abc", "Def"))",
            data: {
                'id':InvoiceId,
                'selectedid':selectedIds,
                'method':'Ground'
            },
            success: function (response) {

            },
          });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Id attribute to custom button:

```
toolbar: [{ name: "create", id : "btnTest"}]
```

On success function use this id like below:

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#btnTest").hide();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     // after grid initialization
     $("#CustomButton").kendoButton().data("kendoButton");
}
```

And in the success function of the ajax call use: `$("#customButton").hide();`

Comment: Can you post more from your code? The solution I provided asa tested in the kendo dojo and was working.

Comment: Please See Image In My Question